# First Person Camera Roll

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, camera, quaternions

I am writing a java Game Engine for OpenGL using LWJGL and OpenGL 3.2.
Whenever the mouse is moved to rotate the camera it adds roll as well as pitch and yaw.

Camera code

```
public Matrix4f getViewMatrix() {
    getParent().getTransform().getWorldRot().mul(rotation, (Quaternion) null).toRotationMatrix(viewMatrix);
    viewMatrix.mul(Matrix4f.setTranslation(getParent().getTransform().getWorldPos(), null));
    return viewMatrix;
}


public boolean mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.x / 1f), rotation.getUp(null)), rotation);
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.y / 1f), rotation.getRight(null)), rotation);
    return true;
}
```

Quaternion code

```
public Vector4f getRight(Vector4f dest) {
    if (dest == null)
        dest = new Vector4f();

    dest.x = 1.0f - 2.0f * (y * y + z * z);
    dest.y = 2.0f * (x * y - w * z);
    dest.z = 2.0f * (x * z + w * y);

    return dest;
}

public Vector4f getUp(Vector4f dest) {
    if (dest == null)
        dest = new Vector4f();

    dest.x = 2.0f * (x * y + w * z);
    dest.y = 1.0f - 2.0f * (x * x + z * z);
    dest.z = 2.0f * (y * z - w * x);

    return dest;
}

public Vector4f getForward(Vector4f dest) {
    if (dest == null)
        dest = new Vector4f();

    dest.x = 2.0f * (x * z - w * y);
    dest.y = 2.0f * (y * z + w * x);
    dest.z = 1.0f - 2.0f * (x * x + y * y);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to get the up.

```
public boolean mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.x / 1f), Vector4f.UP), rotation);
    Quaternion.mul(rotation, new Quaternion((float) Math.toRadians(event.y / 1f), rotation.getRight(null)), rotation);
    return true;
}
```